# Why am I not able to show or hide in Internet Explorer 8, and how I can fix the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I have written JavaScript code to show and hide the div. But I got stuck when it is not working in Internet Explorer 8. It is working smoothly in other browsers, like Opera, Firefox etc.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Show Hide Div Visibility</title>

        <style type="text/css">
        </style>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function showHideDiv()
        {
            var divstyle = new String();
            divstyle = document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility;
            if(divstyle.toLowerCase()=="visible" || divstyle == "")
            {
                document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="div1" class="divStyle">
            <object width="300" height="300">
                <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/7_6B6vwE83U">
                </param>
                <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/7_6B6vwE83U"
                       type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                       width="300"
                       height="300">
                </embed>
            </object>
        </div>

        <center>
             <div onclick="showHideDiv()">Click Me For show hide <div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could just $("#div1").toggle() with jQuery

Comment: Or not... jQuery is not needed in this case

Comment: Your code looks fine. I tried your code, it's working in IE 8.  Clear IE8 Browser cache and try again.

Comment: Don't forget to declare a doctype - IE8 is a bit sensitive... http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: @mplungjan jQuery is never _needed_ but it makes things like this easier especially when you're worried about browser inconsistencies :)

Comment: Sure. But it is such a knee-jerk answer here at SO.

Comment: is this HTML file is located on your computer? then IE will restrict running from script. You need to allow the blocked content.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
if(div1.style.display=="none" || div1.style.display == ""){
  document.getElementById("div1").style.diplay = "block";
}
else{
  div1.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Why change from visibility to display? - if one does not work, the other won't either. And display will collapse the space. Also it was already suggested by DanielB

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display`:

```
function showHideDiv()
{
    var divstyle = new String();
    divstyle = document.getElementById("div1").style.display;
    if(divstyle.toLowerCase()=="block" || divstyle == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display= "none";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display= "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not remove the item from the DOM. You may be right with your comment if you mean, the space the item uses, collapses after hiding with `display: none`, but the OP wasn't that specific in his question.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. But there is in my opinion absolutely no difference in coding between the two, so if one did not work, the other would also not. So pointless suggestion in any case

Comment: No, it's not pointless. The usage of `visibility` differs in browsers, `display` does not.

Comment: @Daniel: Example please of the difference from a javascript point of view between style.display and style.visibility other than style.display can have more values and will behave differently when using "block" or ""

Comment: From JavaScript point of view there is no difference, and I never mentioned that. It's all about the CSS 'visibility' property not JavaScript at all.

Comment: @mplungjan btw: why should it be a JavaScript problem if it works in other browsers?

Comment: Why would display work better than visibility? I have no issues in IE8 here http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7bxrB/

Comment: We may discuss this endless, even if it works in IE8 'visiblity' worked different in older IE version. And it may be, that my answer didn't is that helpful. Finally the OP has to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is your best friend when working with DOM.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.trigger').click(function(){
            $('#div1').toggleClass('hidden');
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="div1" class="divStyle">
    <object width="300" height="300">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/7_6B6vwE83U"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/7_6B6vwE83U" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="300"></embed>
    </object> 
</div>

<center>
    <div class="trigger">Click Me For show hide</div>
</center>
```

Comment: i tied what you have but it is still not working in any browser plz chech it and reply

Comment: Yep, provided you have included [jQuery.js](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery), it works just fine ([see this](http://jsfiddle.net/3CBPp/))

Answer (score 0):

Your page works just fine in Firefox 4 and Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP.

Yours: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2KZ47/

Mine: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7bxrB/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Show Hide Div Visibility</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .center {text-align:center}
            #div1 {visibility:visible}
        </style>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function showHideDiv() {
               var div = document.getElementById("div1");
               div.style.visibility=(div.style.visibility==="visible"||div.style.visibility==="")?"hidden":"visible";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="div1" class="divStyle">
        ...
        </div>

        <div class="center" onclick="showHideDiv()">Click Me For show hide <div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The respondents that have tested it all report that it works fine in their IE8. That would leave three options open:

1. No Doctype declaration (I'm assuming the testers put that over it manually).
2. It concerned an intranet site, temporarily or permanently. IE8+ has a Compatibility Mode/View (= IE7), which it defaults to in case an intranet site is requested. Exceptions are made for sites of which the URL starts with 'localhost' of '127.0.0.1', the address of the on-computer server(-simulator), if installed.
3. The OP had his IE8 set to 'View all sites in Compatibility Mode/View'.

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter property `(style.filter)` that IE8 sets it to `alpha(opacity=0)`. Just set it to **undefined** and the element pops up again.