# Ajax loader gif won't display in IE 8

Tags: jquery

I've read a lot of posts on this but nothing the solved the problem.

I added an IMG tag (for an ajax loader gif) to the page with a style attribute (visibility:hidden), and added event handlers for 2 jQuery ajax events: ajaxStart (to show() the image) and ajaxStop (to hide() the image).

It works fine in Firefox but in IE 8 the image is never displayed. I put alerts in the ajaxStart and ajaxStop event handlers to confirm they fire, and they do.

I also tried a using a plain non-animated gif, but the results were the same: works fine in Firefox but nothing is ever displayed in IE 8.

Answer (score 3):

instead of hiding it with css in the beginning use Jquery to hide it ( $("img").hide() ) on page load. and on ajax start use $("img").show() and for stop use $("img").hide() .

---

**Edit**
Also, if we all stop supporting IE8 (and all IE in general) the world will be a better place.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, jquery `.slow` changes css display value, not visibility.

Can I see some code?

Try some [Why am I not able to show or hide in Internet Explorer 8, and how I can fix the problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263142/why-am-i-not-able-to-show-or-hide-in-internet-explorer-8-and-how-i-can-fix-the-p) and see if one of those helps.

Comment: I tried css display with no luck; same results as I described; thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use image url instead of using hide/show.

you may use `background-image: url(loader.gif);`

and then change it to;

`background-image: url();`