# How to run a selenium webdriver script written in java using IE driver in silent mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have written my selenium webdriver scripts in java and want to run them in IE but without opening a Browser. Is there any options to do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263142/why-am-i-not-able-to-show-or-hide-in-internet-explorer-8-and-how-i-can-fix-the

Comment: Need how to test a selenium webdriver in Java without opening a browser in IE

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11);
```

Reference: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.html